# 90 day stay is almost up but waiting for citizenship papers

Tags: canadian-citizens

I have been in Germany approx. 80 days and am waiting for my approval of citizenship. It could show up any day now. I am a Canadian citizen and have a applied for dual citizenship as I have German heritage - mother and father had German Citizenship when I was born in Canada. If I do not receive it before my 90 days is up would I have to go back to Canada or would it be ok if I stayed until I receive my German Citizenship?

Comment: No, you don't have to return. If you are a German in Germany, end of story. Paperwork notwithstanding (assuming you have copies of the evidence you already submitted). You also have suspensive appeal rights.  This should be on expats, close voting as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks you for the info. Should I still see an immigration Lawyer and get a letter stating I did so just in case I have problems?

Comment: @Gayot, who says R.Christen "is German"? In some countries, citizenship is granted automatically based on a principle; while in others, it is not effective until the documentation is issued. Which is it in R.Christen's case?

Comment: @DouglasHeld in most cases the operation of citizenship law is automatic. I am pretty sure that's true of German *jus sanguinis.* In any event, the suspensive appeal means that while the application is pending it's not necessary to leave the country.

Comment: @R.Christen there's no benefit to being able to document that you've seen a lawyer.  If you have a good deal of money and want to pay for some peace of mind, go for it. But normally it's not only not necessary to leave a country when an immigration-related application is pending, it's a bad idea.In your case, its probably not a bad idea, but it's certainly unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need help from us. You need to contact a qualified immigration lawyer.

This is entirely baseless advice, but in my personal experience overstaying a visa in the UK, I was advised by a lawyer after I left that I would have been in a much better negotiating position had I stayed in the UK and tried to make amends from there.